# Creating a genealogical tree java

Tags: java, tree

I have the following structure:

```
Member {
    String firstName;
    String secondName;
    Member[] children;
    Member father;
}
```

- I have to implement this tree in java;
- I have a first name and a second name of a member. I need to find the way from root to that node. 
  Can someone help me, please?

This is what i have:

public class Member {

```
public List<Member> children = new ArrayList<>();
public Member father = null;
public String secondName = null;
public String firstName = null;

public Member(String secondName, String firstName) {
    this.secondName = secondName;
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

public Member(String secondName, String firstName, Member father) {
    this.secondName = secondName;
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.father = father;
}

public List<Member> getChildren() {
    return children;
}

public void setFather(Member father) {
    this.father = father;
    father.addChild(this);

}

public void addChild(String secondName, String firstName) {
    Member child = new Member(secondName, firstName);
    child.setFather(this);
    this.children.add(child);
}

public void addChild(Member child) {
    child.setFather(this);
    this.children.add(child);
}

public String getSecondName() {
    return this.secondName;
}

public String getFirstName() {
    return this.firstName;
}

public void setSecondName(String secondName) {
    this.secondName = secondName;
}

public void setPrenume(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

public boolean isRoot() {
    return (this.father == null);
}

public void deleteFather() {
    this.father = null;
}
```

}

Comment: You can use depth first search, I believe, here is a video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uT1p5Eiw9CE . Here is some code for tree traversals https://www.google.by/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBwQFjAAahUKEwjxqceR6rfHAhULtBQKHR_ICDM&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cis.upenn.edu%2F~matuszek%2Fcit594-2003%2FExamples%2FTreeTraversals%2FTreeTraversals.java&ei=fd7VVbH3K4voUp-Qo5gD&usg=AFQjCNHKBOfuqH3IfXNcpywoA0Pz3KSkUA&sig2=S_yyyUdmkoNq8tuTClvq7w&bvm=bv.99804247,d.d24&cad=rja . And here is a wiki article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal

Comment: If you want help/guidance with implementing a tree, you could derive `DefaultTreeModel`, supplying it with your `Member` class, which therfore would implement the `TreeNode` interface.

Comment: Thank you, i know it isn't very difficult, but i am new to java. :(

Comment: @SME_Dev in fact, what he has defined is already a tree.

Comment: @DanilGaponov i know that, but OP still seems "to miss the forest for the trees".^^

Answer (score 3):

Your structure is similar to ona which i have in my application. I solve this problem by creating generic walker, which walks down the three from the root, and using visitor pattern to provide me result of walk.

If you convert it into your problem it will looks like that:

```
public class SimpleWalker<T>{

    private Visitor<T> visitor;


    public SimpleWalker(Visitor<T> visitor) {
        this.visitor= visitor;
    }

    public void walk(Member node) {


        if (visitor.visit(node)) {
            for (Member  child : node.children) {
                walk(child);
            }
        }
        visitor.leave(node);

    }

    public T getResult() {
        return visitor.getResult();
    }

}
```

then visitor interface

```
public interface Visitor<T> {
    boolean visit(Member   node);
    void leave(Member   node);
    T getResult();
}
```

and implementation will looks like that

```
public class Pathfinder implements Visitor<List<Member>> {
        final private String firstname, secondname;//passed by constructor
        boolean found = false;
        List<Member> path = new ArrayList<>();

        public boolean visit(Member node) {
            if (node.firstname.equals(firstname)
                    && node.secondname.equals(secondname)) {
                found = true;
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }

        public void leave(Member node) {
            if (found){
                path.add(0, node);
            }
        }

        public List<Member> getResult() {
            return path;
        }
    }
```

advantage of this solution is, whatever you want to do something in tree, such us find element, count number of descendants of somebody, you can use walker, all what you need to do is create new visitor.

Comment: how can i create new visitor?

Comment: @GabrielComănescu  if you want instantiate Pathfinder, you just do `Pathfinder visitor = new Pathfinder("joe","blobsky")` note that, you need to implement constructor which takes 2 string arguments. if you want to create new custom visitor, just implement `Visitor` interface

Answer (score 1):

This Github project might help if you want to create a Family Tree using Java swing:

https://github.com/r-deleon/familyTree

It uses yFiles for Java library..